# Parse ISO 8601 date format in django tables2

Tags: python, django, datetime, iso8601, django-tables2

I am using [django tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#datetimecolumn) which:

> Note that format uses Django’s date template tag syntax.

According to [django date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) ISO 8601 is selected by the format string 'c':

> c ISO 8601 format: 2008-01-02T10:30:00.000123+02:00

So that's what I do:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

...

    created = tables.DateTimeColumn(format='c')
```

But that does not work (the `created` column in the table is shown empty, a sign of parsing problems)

This is the data coming from the API:

```
"created": "2018-09-05T14:00:35.672433Z",
```

which is actually coming from [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield), which by default uses:

> format - A string representing the output format. If not specified,
>   this defaults to the same value as the DATETIME_FORMAT settings key,
>   which will be 'iso-8601' unless set

To summarize, my question is:

How to parse iso8601 with django tables2?

### EDIT

Table population is done as follows:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class ExpansionTable(tables.Table):
    human = tables.Column()
    created = tables.DateTimeColumn(format='c')
    size = tables.Column()
    description = tables.Column()
    output = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table paleblue'}
        order_by = "-created"
```

This will show empty values (`—`) for the `created` column. The rest of the columns are shown as expected.

Comment: How are you populating the data in the table?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid As said, the data comes from the API, not from a table. And yes, the data is there. Actually, if instead of using a `DateTimeColumn` I just use a `Column`, the information is displayed, using plain text widget.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you use to populate the table with the data that is coming from the API.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid updated.

Comment: Sometimes the suffix "Z" leads to problems. Just to check, try to replace it with "+00:00".

Comment: @Risadinha good idea, but difficult to test, since the formatting is done via default DRF config. I would need to get the right formatting string for DRF to do that.

Comment: @Risadinha mmm, no luck. `'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'` in the DRF side gives: `"created": "2018-09-05T14:00:35.672433+0000"` on the API side, but the column `created = tables.DateTimeColumn(format='c')` does not parse that ... :(

Comment: Hi, weird. In the worst case you can define a custom `render_foo` method to perform the parse there and return the format that you want. Take a look [here](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo). Probably you will have to define the `order_foo` method if you need so sort it as well.

Comment: "does not parse that" - you have to find out why that is, and I think Jieter has a good find in his answer. Not getting an error message could mean: the template engine decides to just ignore the variable values - without throwing an error. Which would (imho) indicate that it's not just a parsing problem.

Answer (score 1):

django-tables2 expects the incoming data for `DateTimeColumn` to be an actual `datetime` instance, this is the implementation:

```
def __init__(self, format=None, short=True, *args, **kwargs):
    if format is None:
        format = "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" if short else "DATETIME_FORMAT"
    template = '{{ value|date:"%s"|default:default }}' % format
    super(DateTimeColumn, self).__init__(template_code=template, *args, **kwargs)
```

So I guess you have two options:

1. write a custom column or use a [`render_foo` methods](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods) to make sure the data is correctly rendered in the table
2. Transform the string values to `datetime` instances before passing on the data to django-tables2.

I would suggest to use 2.